# Disable Live Messenger's Link Nanny

Tags: windows-live-messenger

In the new Windows Live Messenger there's a link nanny built in. I.e. When you click links it sends you first to a page `"You are now leaving Live Messenger"` etc... designed to help protect people who don't know better from following fishy (or phishy :D) links sent to them.

This is really annoying for me as a user who generally knows what I'm doing, I can spot a fishy link, or just know well enough not to open links I don't know about.

But when I'm collaborating with a colleague and we're passing `pastebin.com` urls back and forth it's incredibly annoying to have to do this EVERY TIME.

Is there a way to turn this feature off. Where's the `"I'm not an idiot"` setting in Live Messenger?

What's more is this feature doesn't even really protect you, it doesn't look ahead to the site you're going to, checking if it's on a blacklist or known to be dangerous. It just makes you have to click once more to go where you want to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to disable it but there are workarounds. If you use IE you could try turning SmartScreen off in the security menu.

[Here's a Chrome extension you can use](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lfiplcfmljjbhdmbboiidbomniiakcko?hl=en)

[Here's a GreaseMonkey script you can use for Firefox](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/01/28/bypass-the-microsoft-smartscreen-filter/)